# R - plm regression with time in posix-format

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I have little experience with panel data in R, and am trying to run a simple panel regression with the plm-package. When converting my dataframe to a pdata.frame, however, my time index-variable is transformed to a factor variable. This means that if I want to regress a dependent variable as a function of time, the regression generates a long list of dummy-variables for time and calculates individual coefficients for each. I just want the average effect per time unit (ie. average monthly increase/decrease in points).

Example dataframe:

```
ID    Date        Points
1     1/11/2014   2
1     1/12/2014   4
1     1/1/2015    6
1     1/2/2015    8
2     1/11/2014   1
2     1/12/2014   2
2     1/1/2015    3
2     1/2/2015    4
```

Say the example dataframe structure is ID = int, Date = POSIXct, Points = int.
I then convert it to a pdata.frame with index ID and Date:

```
panel <- pdata.frame(dataframe, c("ID", "Date"))
```

And run a plm fixed effects regression:

```
fixed <- plm(Points ~ Date, data=panel, model="within")
summary(fixed)
```

The resulting coefficients are then broken down by each month as dummies.
I want to treat my time-variable as a continuous variable, so I get only one coefficient for Date. How can I do this? Is there a way to avoid formatting the time index-variable as a factor in panel dataframes?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to create a separate clock or time counter from `panel$Date` to use in your model. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe <- dataframe %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(clock = seq_along(ID))
panel <- pdata.frame(dataframe, c("ID", "Date"))
```

That produces these data:

```
             ID       Date Points clock
1-2014-11-01  1 2014-11-01      2     1
1-2014-12-01  1 2014-12-01      4     2
1-2015-01-01  1 2015-01-01      6     3
1-2015-02-01  1 2015-02-01      8     4
2-2014-11-01  2 2014-11-01      1     1
2-2014-12-01  2 2014-12-01      2     2
2-2015-01-01  2 2015-01-01      3     3
2-2015-02-01  2 2015-02-01      4     4
```

That produces this output:

```
> fixed <- plm(Points ~ clock, data=panel, model="within")
> summary(fixed)
Oneway (individual) effect Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = points ~ clock, data = panel, model = "within")

Balanced Panel: n=2, T=4, N=8

Residuals :
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -0.750  -0.375   0.000   0.375   0.750 

Coefficients :
      Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)   
clock  1.50000    0.22361  6.7082 0.001114 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    25
Residual Sum of Squares: 2.5
R-Squared      :  0.9 
      Adj. R-Squared :  0.5625 
F-statistic: 45 on 1 and 5 DF, p-value: 0.0011144
```

Comment: Could whoever down-voted this answer please explain why?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though it seems the whole thread got hit by downvotes. The seq_along solution is a good idea and works for my simplistic example dataset, but what if the dataset has different start and stop times? Say id=2 is instead first observed 1/12/2014 and last observed 1/3/2014, then the clock-variable would set both (id=1, date=2014-11-01) and (id=2, date=2014-12-01) as clock=1. Is there a better way?

Comment: It depends on what kind of relationship between time and Points you want to explore. If you think the specific dates matter, then your original model is actually the right one. If it's time elapsed since the start of observation, then the approach I suggest would work fine even if the start dates differ. If it's something else, then you'll need a different approach.

Comment: Good points. I actually think the specific dates matter in the sense that higher points are more likely with later dates. For the moment I'm just trying to recreate the results I got in Stata. Your approach comes very close to those results, but Stata seems to be able to handle different start/end-times without creating time-dummies which I believe makes the difference.

Comment: @ulfeledr It seems you're very knowledgeable in both Stata in R. Could you help me out translating a similiar Stata code into R? Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Econ_Spectre, I'm not sure where you got the impression that I am proficient in Stata, but I'm not. Haven't used it in decades. Good luck.